# Can I add UIImageView inside custom UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uialertview

I already have a custom UIAlertView and in which i want to add UIImageView for adding custom UIAlertView.

I have already added UIImageView with array and start animating it but it doesn't work. If you want, I can post the code.

Please help me ASAP. I'm stuck :(

Here is code

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image text:(NSString *)text
{

    //CGSize imageSize = self.backgroundImage.size;
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    width = frame.size.width; 
    height = frame.size.height;

    if (self = [super init])
    {



        loadtext = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        loadtext.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        loadtext.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self addSubview:loadtext];

        //Create the first status image and the indicator view
        UIImage *statusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"status1.png"];
        activityImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                                          initWithImage:statusImage];


        //Add more images which will be used for the animation
        activityImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"status1.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"status2.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"status3.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"status4.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"status5.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"status6.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"status7.png"],
                                             nil];


        //Set the duration of the animation (play with it
        //until it looks nice for you)
        activityImageView.animationDuration = 1.0;


        //Position the activity image view somewhere in 
        //the middle of your current view
        activityImageView.frame = CGRectZero;

        //Start the animation
        [activityImageView startAnimating];


        //Add your custom activity indicator to your current view
        [self addSubview:activityImageView];



        //self.backgroundImage = image;



    }
    return self;
}

- (void) layoutSubviews{
    //lblUserName.transform = CGAffineTransformMake;
    //[lblUserName sizeToFit];

    CGRect textRect = activityImageView.frame;
    textRect.origin.x = (CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(textRect))/2;
    textRect.origin.y = (CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(textRect))/2;
    textRect.origin.x -= 100.0;
    textRect.origin.y -= 60.0;
    textRect.size.height = 30;
    textRect.size.width = self.bounds.size.width - 50;

    activityImageView.frame = textRect;
}
```

This code started working. But now this UIImageView is taking my whole screen and coming in front of UIAlertView. Though i give 10px height and width. It shows same. Can anyone help please?

Thanks,
Anks

Comment: could you post the code where you add the image to the alert view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add image view - in custom alert-view. instead of taking as UIView  custom class, need to take UIImage-View & you can use image-view properties.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Change `activityImageView.frame = CGRectZero;`

to some custom frame.

eg:

```
activityImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
```

Comment: It's already going to layoutSubview and changing it. I have tried with this already but it doesn't work :(